# Convert multidimensional array with unknown amount arrays into single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm bit new to arrays and got severely bugged on this. so i hope someone can help :)

I am having user to enter opening hours of their shops through the form, in the end i am getting an array of values. I do not know how many arrays actually gets created, as that controlled by user, what i know is that it it will be somewhere between 3 and 9.

The array i end up with looks something like this:

```php
Array ( 
[opening_hours_start] => Array ( 
[0] => 18:30 
[1] => 18:30 
[2] => 09:00 ) 
[opening_hours_end] => Array ( 
[0] => 22:00 
[1] => 23:00 
[2] => 18:00 ) 
[weekday] => Array ( 
[0] => 1 
[1] => 2 
[2] => 3 
[3] => 5 ) 
[weekday2] => Array ( 
[0] => 4 ) 
[weekday3] => Array ( 
[0] => 6 
[1] => 7 ) 
)
```

What i want to end up in the end would be something like this:

```
Array(
[1] => Array (
[start] => 18:30
[end] => 22:00)
[2] => Array (
[start] => 18:30
[end] => 22:00)

etc.

)
)
```

Any array magicians around here, that could give me a hand?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

okay so this is how i solved it in the end:

```
  $opening_hours = $original_array;
  $opening_hours_start = $opening_hours['opening_hours_start'];
  $opening_hours_end = $opening_hours['opening_hours_end'];

  unset($opening_hours['opening_hours_start']);
  unset($opening_hours['opening_hours_end']);

  $weekdays_array = $opening_hours;

  $array = array();

  $i = 0;

  foreach ($weekdays_array as $weekday_set => $weekdays) {

    foreach($weekdays as $weekday) {

      $data = [
        'weekday' => $weekday,
        'start' => $opening_hours_start[$i], 
        'end' => $opening_hours_end[$i]];

      array_push($array, $data);

    }
    $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eaf6d78b4180843407f430629a4e745c5f2c86c1)

```
$result = array_map(function($start,$end){
    return array(
        "start"=>$start,
        "end"=>$end
    );
},$array["opening_hours_start"],$array["opening_hours_end"]);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hmm, close, but not quite there yet. Now reading my question after bit of sleep i can see I wasn't fully clear. 

Basically `[weekday][weekday2][weekday3]` represents the days that hours belong to, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday etc. so essentially `[weekday]` values belong to `[opening_hours_start][0]` and `[opening_hours_end][0]`

`[weekday2]` values belong to `[opening_hours_start[1]` and `[opening_hours_end][1]`. 

Hope that makes more sense as to what i'm trying to achieve.